# Forcing b-PAC to generate DataMatrix barcodes of a specific symbol size

Tags: c#, datamatrix, brother-bpac

I am using Brother's b-PAC3.2 SDK in C# to generate and print DataMatrix barcodes using a Brother label printer. My application uses a template created using their P-touch Editor that just has the barcode and a label.

The problem I am having is that the barcode automatically uses the smallest possible symbol size to fit the data, and the client is requesting that the application defaults to 16x16 for all barcodes regardless of the length of the serial number for the sake of consistency. Their serial numbers range anywhere from 5-16ish numbers/characters, so the barcodes generated by the SDK range from 10x10 to 16x16.

They are currently using an online barcode generator which allows them to do just that, so I know it is possible. But the option to set the preferred size of the barcode doesn't seem to be exposed in the P-Touch Editor or the b-PAC SDK. I've gone through the documentation for both the P-Touch Editor and the b-PAC SDK and this option is nowhere to be found.

Am I missing something? This seems like a pretty basic request, so it's odd to me that Brother would have omitted the option to do this.

Comment: See following P-Touch Editor : https://www.brother.co.jp/eng/dev/bpac/faq/index.aspx

Comment: The question isn't answered anywhere in that FAQ.

Comment: Question : Can I change bar code size Answer : Yes. You can change it with b-PAC SDK Ver.3.0.
For b-PAC SDK Ver.2.0 and earlier versions, you need to do the following.
For example, ........ See link for more.

Comment: That is referring to changing the scale of the barcode. I'm talking about changing the symbol size. It's not the same thing. [Here is a size chart for DataMatrix barcodes](https://identifydirect.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/SizeDataCapacityChart.pdf) - What I am talking about is the left-most column: Symbol Size. This is what determines how much data a DataMatrix can hold.

Comment: So maybe the margins on the paper is set wrong or the FIT Page option on the printer is wrong.